# WCF Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message

Tags: c#, wcf, security, .net-4.0, certificate

First off, i'm a WCF Novice so it is very possible i'm doing something very trivial very wrong. Anyhow, i'm currently in the proces of developing a WCF service which uses wsHttpBinding in order to communicate, and the clientCredentialType Username.

WCF Dictates the use of a credential in order to encrypt the communication (i've set this up "quick and dirty" since i don't have the production certs yet.).

When i'm developing or testing the service straight from visual studio so the address becomes something like http://localhost:123223/Checks.svc everything works fine, how ever if i deploy the exact project to a website on my development machine i the following exception:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other
>   party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

With the following stacktrace:

> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message
>   reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation
>   operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken
>   currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel
>   channel, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan
>   timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   TestCreditExchangeWCFServices.CreditExchange.WCF.Services.IChecks.CreditCheck(CreditCheck
>   creditCheck1)    at
>   TestCreditExchangeWCFServices.CreditExchange.WCF.Services.ChecksClient.CreditCheck(CreditCheck
>   creditCheck1) in
>   D:\Projects\Temp\TestCreditExchangeWCFServices\TestCreditExchangeWCFServices\Service
>   References\CreditExchange.WCF.Services\Reference.cs:line 1793    at
>   TestCreditExchangeWCFServices.MainWindow.btnLite_Click(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e) in
>   D:\Projects\Temp\TestCreditExchangeWCFServices\TestCreditExchangeWCFServices\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
>   39

Server configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="CreditExchange.WCF.Services.Checks">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding" contract="CreditExchange.WCF.Services.IChecks">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!--<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />-->
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles" roleProviderName="NHibernateRoleProvider" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                              storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider"
              membershipProviderName="CredentialsProvider" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <errorHandler />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="errorHandler"
              type="Common.Library.WCF.Exceptions.UnhandledExceptionHandlerExtension, Common.Library" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IChecks" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <!--<endpoint address="http://localhost:52744/Checks.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IChecks" contract="CreditExchange.WCF.Services.IChecks"
          name="WSHttpBinding_IChecks">-->
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/CreditExchange.WCF.Services/Checks.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IChecks" contract="CreditExchange.WCF.Services.IChecks"
        name="WSHttpBinding_IChecks">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <!-- Needed because otherwise we get errors because the Cert chain can not be verified -->
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I've googled it and i've seen mentioning of timestamp problems causing this issue but i simply do not understand how on the exact same machine something that runs in a VS Debug environment runs fine, but published throws an error which i can't wrap my head around.

I enabled tracing on the client which shows the following exception (not that that makes sense to me):

```
Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.
```

I've traced two messages, one succesfull (on my debugged version) and one which fails, i'm looking at differences, and the only thing i can see is the Via tag (one aims at my FQDN for some reason, instead of localhost) And the AppDomain is different (which makes sense)

Succesfull:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>262163</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
<Level>8</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-09-06T10:04:03.6960710Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{1a2bd6e0-c785-468b-95ea-d8b464abec94}" />
<Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="2792" ThreadID="31" />
<Channel />
<Computer>PC-FOLKERT</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageReceived.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Received a message over a channel.</Description>
<AppDomain>f67db61a-2-129597770339060921</AppDomain>
<Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext+HostedHttpInput/64865147</Source>
<ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTransmitTraceRecord">
<MessageProperties>
<Encoder>application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8</Encoder>
<AllowOutputBatching>False</AllowOutputBatching>
<Via>http://localhost:52744/Checks.svc</Via>
</MessageProperties>
<MessageHeaders>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_4" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT</a:Action>
<a:MessageID u:Id="_5" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:7117ff27-a64b-4b86-9f80-127225fd3e44</a:MessageID>
<ActivityId CorrelationId="4878f073-6eed-4f48-a8a1-bc792112cfd8" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ActivityId>
<a:ReplyTo u:Id="_6" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_7" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://localhost:52744/Checks.svc</a:To>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-54189139-4404-4f93-a197-4438ab5f3fde-5" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<u:Created>2011-09-06T10:04:03.580Z</u:Created>
<u:Expires>2011-09-06T10:09:03.580Z</u:Expires>
</u:Timestamp>
<c:SecurityContextToken u:Id="uuid-c4807903-c4a0-4ef0-9712-bd05f8788780-1" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<c:Identifier>urn:uuid:e3f5c663-9b49-45b6-8774-5292da16ca2e</c:Identifier>
</c:SecurityContextToken>
<c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="_0" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" URI="#uuid-c4807903-c4a0-4ef0-9712-bd05f8788780-1"></o:Reference>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
<c:Offset>0</c:Offset>
<c:Length>24</c:Length>
<c:Nonce>
<!-- Removed-->
</c:Nonce>
</c:DerivedKeyToken>
<c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="_1" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" URI="#uuid-c4807903-c4a0-4ef0-9712-bd05f8788780-1"></o:Reference>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
<c:Nonce>
<!-- Removed-->
</c:Nonce>
</c:DerivedKeyToken>
<e:ReferenceList xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:DataReference URI="#_3"></e:DataReference>
<e:DataReference URI="#_8"></e:DataReference>
<e:DataReference URI="#_9"></e:DataReference>
</e:ReferenceList>
<e:EncryptedData Id="_9" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"></e:EncryptionMethod>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" URI="#_1"></o:Reference>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<e:CipherData>
<e:CipherValue>T9HGceq5Weq5n5Cygk/YzOb9JRFrJVGLdgB+Bf2cDcwue6/Wf5HUg0Krl35/e05wtuwTwNNCH4Q9a8e8+J9+L68tYVijYKwlxJZBIEHLx2XCCKqbve6DWc3VYmaX8mNqDXtKC8cfAtW1O5oH8m/6lCnuN+sZoQDgYh97S5f7AusJdT+eTb9OFarhH5HwiupUjERpnYWAXWoSUgjjCKxIp0iD+MpRGCGA2/7xt+WvfDgX2B/c1DvzuWwx+Kwv7HiXeHS6ZVfnTTYZO3e4GTq7TDYtMThLvw3hGOkK5nb/IDOlGLqWEBk4tzdKgIn7FGssOdhohXyYIAj7x3wzyEirg+HRLg7OO/rtrG0jw/jLdIzs627Hypdbrm9mckAdtxFbh/5p3/CYmGuTr/2ck4EW/a5AM8nkn6J1QT4Cp14Ckr4ZjbvivMKAwGtTcmaJQm6h053b6KOW2lGxO3z+kOjYrE94K993hLvjFfK99LRM1yyApCQyRNMEaKJWNaONmpfdSEAcfrpx+bp0+Fohm1D+8AyYL0m4+tSign7btWZFwU5y8P7ggVQuGrJ0ew0EpDscurFL9FOfZf4H6+qidH305o4CkY0BZanwb6kDhLzxA/0=</e:CipherValue>
</e:CipherData>
</e:EncryptedData>
<e:EncryptedData Id="_8" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"></e:EncryptionMethod>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" URI="#_1"></o:Reference>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<e:CipherData>
<e:CipherValue>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</e:CipherValue>
</e:CipherData>
</e:EncryptedData>
</o:Security>
</MessageHeaders>
</ExtendedData>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Failure:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>262163</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
<Level>8</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-09-06T10:38:36.3276859Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{fba8e1c9-a9f9-491e-814a-e1b513188bcc}" />
<Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="1896" ThreadID="13" />
<Channel />
<Computer>PC-FOLKERT</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageReceived.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Received a message over a channel.</Description>
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/CreditExchange.WCF.Services-3-129597790759646859</AppDomain>
<Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext+HostedHttpInput/3683710</Source>
<ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTransmitTraceRecord">
<MessageProperties>
<Encoder>application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8</Encoder>
<AllowOutputBatching>False</AllowOutputBatching>
<Via>http://pc-folkert.domain.local/CreditExchange.WCF.Services/Checks.svc</Via>
</MessageProperties>
<MessageHeaders>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_4" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT</a:Action>
<a:MessageID u:Id="_5" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:3352b0d1-a569-4d59-a377-82730c5d07f2</a:MessageID>
<ActivityId CorrelationId="dfd3e02f-53ef-4b33-a5a4-43bb5bf71245" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ActivityId>
<a:ReplyTo u:Id="_6" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_7" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://localhost/CreditExchange.WCF.Services/Checks.svc</a:To>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-6f05a6c6-cffa-492e-ae65-4e02b33a0ef1-5" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<u:Created>2011-09-06T10:38:36.249Z</u:Created>
<u:Expires>2011-09-06T10:43:36.249Z</u:Expires>
</u:Timestamp>
<c:SecurityContextToken u:Id="uuid-63efd986-fc21-47db-84eb-735045c57539-2" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<c:Identifier>urn:uuid:67a5014b-b3e0-4f91-a730-60a2a36d3cbe</c:Identifier>
</c:SecurityContextToken>
<c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="_0" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" URI="#uuid-63efd986-fc21-47db-84eb-735045c57539-2"></o:Reference>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
<c:Offset>0</c:Offset>
<c:Length>24</c:Length>
<c:Nonce>
<!-- Removed-->
</c:Nonce>
</c:DerivedKeyToken>
<c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="_1" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" URI="#uuid-63efd986-fc21-47db-84eb-735045c57539-2"></o:Reference>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
<c:Nonce>
<!-- Removed-->
</c:Nonce>
</c:DerivedKeyToken>
<e:ReferenceList xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:DataReference URI="#_3"></e:DataReference>
<e:DataReference URI="#_8"></e:DataReference>
<e:DataReference URI="#_9"></e:DataReference>
</e:ReferenceList>
<e:EncryptedData Id="_9" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"></e:EncryptionMethod>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" URI="#_1"></o:Reference>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<e:CipherData>
<e:CipherValue>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</e:CipherValue>
</e:CipherData>
</e:EncryptedData>
<e:EncryptedData Id="_8" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"></e:EncryptionMethod>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" URI="#_1"></o:Reference>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<e:CipherData>
<e:CipherValue>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</e:CipherValue>
</e:CipherData>
</e:EncryptedData>
</o:Security>
</MessageHeaders>
</ExtendedData>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Comment: Enable tracing on the server. There was most probably exception on server side.

Comment: Well, if i add the exact same code to enable tracing on the server, no trace file is even created... Which makes me wonder if anything even reaches the server. Okay, i added the tracing by publishing (think web.config wasn't refreshed or something...) and it traced now, ill comb through it now.

Comment: The only thing i see in the server trace is a warning (not an exception) I'll edit the trace into the question.

Comment: It says that it cannot verify incomming message

Comment: Yes, but why would it have problems verifying it when published through IIS? Yet not have this problem when im running it in Debug? Also, what part does it have problems with? The timestamps? Certificate (i hate certificates, they ruin my life >.<)?

Comment: Okay, looked at the specific message it's recieving when it fails and im noticing that when it goes for the IIS version i have the following message property: <Via>http://pc-folkert.domain.local/CreditExchange.WCF.Services/Checks.svc</Via> (where i'd expect localhost) Although if i aim the same client to the debugged version it has the following: 
<Via>http://localhost:52744/Checks.svc</Via> Not sure if this could be the problem (nor how i'd go about fixing it)

Comment: Are you using any proxy? Is that name of your computer?

Comment: I'm not using any proxy's (that i'm aware off) and yes, that's the name of my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... Well.. I feel ashamed...

Basically after a failed request i'd open the trace log and would get the message the file wasn't closed properly. For some reason the service wouldn't write to it as quickly as i would have expected. I didn't pay any attention to this untill after the lunch (it helps to step back i gues). I scrolled to the right on the "not closed properly" message and noticed it said Exception.

This triggered me since i had only seen a warning in the log so far. So i opened the file in Notepad++ and read the most stupid exception i've seen in a while. It was missing an assembly... (one of the NHibernate assemblies to be exact).

Sadly when i published from VS2010 it didn't publish these assemblies, why is completely beyond me... I just wasted more then two hours of my life because it didn't publish files which it DOES put on the debug bin... That combined with me not looking at these log files properly really did not make my day.

The reason it gives a security error by the way is that we use a membership provider which uses NHibernate to validate a user based...

As is often the case with me i spend way to many hours on a problem which is so easy to fix it brings red to my cheeks... Thanks for the help atleast Ladislav!